# infinity as result in double operation

Tags: cuda, double-precision

I would understand why the result is infinity. I write the code below and I always receive inf as result. There is any precision problem with my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "cuda.h"
#include "curand_kernel.h"

#define NDIM 30
#define NPAR 5

#define DIMPAR NDIM*NPAR

__device__ double uniform(int index){
    return (double) 0.767341;
}


__global__ void iteracao(double *pos){

    int thread = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    double tvel;
    int i = 0;

    double l, r, t;

    if(thread < DIMPAR){
        do{
            t = (double) uniform(thread);
            l = (double) 2.05 * t * ( pos[thread] );
            r = (double) 2.05 * t * ( pos[thread] );
            tvel = (double) l+t+r;
            pos[thread] =  tvel;
            i++;
        }while(i < 10000);
    }

}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    double *d_pos,    *h_pos;


    h_pos = (double *) malloc(sizeof( double ) * DIMPAR);


    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_pos, DIMPAR   * sizeof( double ));


    int i, j, k, numthreadsperblock, numblocks;

    numthreadsperblock = 512;
    numblocks = (DIMPAR / numthreadsperblock) + ((DIMPAR % numthreadsperblock)?1:0);
    //
    printf("numthreadsperblock: %i;; numblocks:%i\n", numthreadsperblock, numblocks);

    cudaMemset(d_pos,  0.767341, DIMPAR   * sizeof( double ));
    iteracao<<<numblocks,numthreadsperblock>>>(d_pos);
    cudaMemcpy(h_pos, d_pos, DIMPAR * sizeof( double ), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    printf("\n");
    for(i = 0; i < NPAR; i++){
        for(j = i*NDIM, k = j; j < (k+30); j++){
            printf("%f,", h_pos[j]);
        }
        printf("***\n\n");
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

the output is always this:

numthreadsperblock: 512;; numblocks:1

inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,***

inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,***

inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,***

inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,***

inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,***

Comment: Most likely you are setting your d_pos to junk.  cudaMemset operates on byte values and you are giving a float which most likely results in just a zero byte.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 problems.  The first is as described by @Anycorn in the comments.  `cudaMemset`, just like `memset` expects a byte value and sets byte locations.  You cannot use it to initialize `float` values.

The second is that your kernel has a loop that is operating 10000 times on each `pos` array element.  In effect you are finding the 10000 factorial of a complicated expression.  Since that expression is always positive, your answer blows up.  In all probability your kernel is not written correctly.  It is not doing what you want it to do.  Even if you fix your first problem and properly initialize `pos` to zero, your calculation will still blow up.

The arithmetic you are performing is:

```
pos[idx] =  0.767341 + (3.1460981 * pos[idx]);
```

For each `idx`, you are performing the above operation 10000 times.  Even for an initial `pos[idx]` value equal to zero, by the 2nd iteration of your loop, it will start to take off geometrically.

Answer (score 1):

You are init `d_pos` in a wrong way. `cudaMemset()` can only set memory byte by byte. see [cudaMemset() doc](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1ge07c97b96efd09abaeb3ca3b5f8da4ee)
 for more details.

To init the array as you intended to, you could use Thrust as a express way.

```
thrust::fill(
    thrust::device_pointer_cast(d_pos),
    thrust::device_pointer_cast(d_pos) + DIMPAR,
    0.767341);
```